# Python: set(sympy.primerange(a, b))

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

(Python 3.5.1)

I've been trying to use Sympy for some Project Euler problems, but I've come across something weird about how `set(sympy.primerange(a, b))` and similar constructions work.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> PR = sympy.primerange(1, 20)
>>> set(PR)
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
```

So far, so good. But:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> PR = sympy.primerange(1, 20)
>>> set(PR)
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
>>> set(PR)
set()
```

Calling simply `PR` gives me `<generator object primerange at 0x039C1720>` after calling `list(PR)` once *or* twice. The same thing happens with `for p in PR: print(p)` and `list(PR)`.

Why does this not work:

```
>>> import sympy, itertools
>>> sympy.sieve.extend(100)
>>> set(itertools.takewhile(lambda p: p<20, sympy.sieve))
set()
>>> sympy.sieve
<Sieve with 25 primes sieved: 2, 3, 5, ... 89, 97>
```

Why don't we get the set `{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first phenomenon is has do to with generators. sympy.primerange returns a **generator**, not a list. Generators let you iterate over their elements once, producing them on demand. The call to set() iterates over every element in the generator PR, consuming it.

itertools.takewhile requires an iterable for its second argument. sympy.sieve is **not** an iterable. It allows you to to request arbitrary primes *by index*, and maintains a dynamic internal sieve. Because sympy.sieve isn't an iterable, takewhile can't extract any elements from it. That's why you don't get your expected results.

Kudos to you for doing Project Euler.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. In digging around the [Sympy API](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/ntheory.html), I figured out that this will work: `>>> sympy.sieve.extend(20) >>> set(sympy.sieve._list)` gives `{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}` and can be called more than once.